# Find Coordinates for boundary of city

Tags: ios, mkmapview

Part of an app I'm making uses MKMapView to display the user's location and zooms in to the near city/town. Now as a next step, I want to highlight the edges of the city as well as certain block (for example, draw a line around the edges of Central Park or Boston Commons). I know how to make an overlay and set it on the map but the problem I can't figure out is out to get the coordinate data for the boundaries.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Which ones in particular do you need?

- [Zillow neighborhood boundaries](http://www.zillow.com/howto/api/neighborhood-boundaries.htm)
- [US Census Bureau data](http://www.census.gov/geo/www/cob/nect2003.html), [more](http://www.census.gov/geo/www/cob/ua2000.html), [more](http://www.census.gov/geo/www/cob/cc2000.html)
- [Maptechnica data](http://www.maptechnica.com/map_tools_cities.php) (for sale)

Comment: I was more wondering if there's a way to do it in Objective-C rather than use an external API simply because those are all for the US only and my app, eventually, will be international. Or that's the hope anyway.

Comment: @shadow be wary of engineering ahead too much.  Use a low-hanging fruit available now while you're taking risks.  Architect so the data can come from other sources

Comment: Yeah Yeah I understand that. I may just forgo the highlighting.